# Trying to get slider to work, "appendTo' not working

Tags: rss, scroll, slider

Trying to fix a widget on my website which displays some RSS feed. Got the scrolling but can't figure out how to restart the scrolling.

I have tried The 'appendTo' but without any succes. I can't find a solution, please help me out.

http://server.info-spot.net/

Regards!

(function($){

$.fn.vTicker = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        speed: 700,
        pause: 3000,
        showItems: 3,
        animation: '',
        mousePause: true,
        isPaused: false
    };

```
var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

moveUp = function(obj2, height, paused){
    if(paused) return;

    var obj = obj2.children('ul');

        first = obj.children('li:first').clone(true);

        obj.animate({top: '-=120px'}, options.speed, function() {
            $(this).children('li:first').remove();

            first.appendTo(obj);
        });

    if(options.animation == 'fade') {
        obj.children('li:first').fadeOut(options.speed);
        obj.children('li:last').hide().fadeIn(options.speed);
    }

        first.appendTo(obj);
};

return this.each(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    var maxHeight = 0;
    var itempause = options.isPaused;

    //obj.css({overflow: 'hidden', position: 'relative'})
    obj.css({position: 'relative'})
        .children('ul').css({position: 'absolute', margin: 0, padding: 0})
        .children('li').css({margin: 0, padding: 0});

    obj.children('ul').children('li').each(function(){

        if($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();
        }
    });

    obj.children('ul').children('li').each(function() {
        $(this).height(maxHeight);
    });

    obj.height(maxHeight * options.showItems);

        var interval = setInterval(function(){ moveUp(obj, maxHeight, itempause); }, options.pause);

    if (options.mousePause)
    {
        obj.bind("mouseenter",function() {
            itempause = true;
        }).bind("mouseleave",function() {
            itempause = false;
        });
    }
});
```

};
})(jQuery);